# London Chess Classic 2013 Format

Tags: rules, tournament, time-control

I have never been into watching live chess, and I found it strange that anyone disagrees with me, but the format of London Chess Classic 2013 was just perfect.

Like the rest of the civilized world, I grew up watching the Football World (known as soccer to Americans), and group stages followed by knockout phase is perfect in my opinion.

The length of each game is perfect 25 min. + 10 sec. I have always thought that thinking too long is cheating (because I can't), and why not just watch two Deep Blues tie after a few hours if you have that classical game fetish?

The scoring system is a no-brainer. Everything should be like football (though I might accept 2 points for being white/home-court and 3 for black/away).

So, after this rant I would ask this to you smarter chess fans: Where I can find similar events?

Comment: the real objection to the format is not the time duration but rather the knockout sequence. having a knockout right from the quarter final stage appears a bit premature. it is possible that the better player may lose due to luck in knockout. in round robin, the more consistent performers rise to the top. for, eg. there can be a round robin amongst the four people with the highest scores in all the 4 groups.

Comment: Well knockout is drama and if chess fans want more recognition of chess than this is good.

Comment: Generally speaking, the chess world prefers purity of competition over "what the masses want". The circumstances of competition sometimes have [very](http://www.snopes.com/sports/soccer/barbados.asp) [odd](http://www.wired.com/playbook/2012/08/badminton-round-robin/) effects.

Comment: Yes and we don't want American time-out in football to watch advertisement but where can I find "chess events for the masses". It would be cool for unelegant noobs like me to know.

Comment: I deleted my post because FIDE has almost nothing related to the Bilbao scoring system as some links call it, or Football scoring as do others.  Try http://www.bilbaomastersfinal.com/en/masters-final/previous-editions/3rd-grand-slam-masters-final-2010/1st-leg-in-shangai/reglamento-del-torneo/

Answer (score 2):

There are other two very important events that follow a different scoring system for the games than the usual W - 1, D - 1/2, L - 0. The first is the Bilbao Masters, you can find information about it on their [main site](http://www.bilbaomastersfinal.com/). Although they do not feature short games, the points awarded are W - 3, D - 1, L - 0. The other is the Zurich Chess Challenge, also interesting information is available on their [main site](http://www.zurich-cc.com/). This event features several blitz, rapid and classical rounds, the blitz pgames only count for the initial standings, while others receive different points (W - 1, D - 1/2, L - 0 for the rapid and W - 2, D - 1, L - 0 for the classical) according to the time controls.

There are very few events that feature a distribution of points per game different to the classic one. But if you are only interested in watching rapid chess, I would consider the first part of the [Tal Memorial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tal_Memorial), the Rapid and Blitz Chess Championships and the tiebreaks of the [World Cup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chess_World_Cup_2015). All of this events are held anually.